# Print function/methods call sequences of any java application

Tags: javascript, java, compilation

I was asked a question by my teacher and I have no ideas what should I do.
Here is my question: Try to print out function/method call sequences of any Java/JavaScript application. 
This is not let me insert printf/console.log in the program. It need to check the function procedure automatically. And my teacher gave me a clue: think about the eclipse.
So where should I start? Any tips would be appreciated for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need access to the environment stack. I don't quite understand what your teacher is asking but I'm guessing they are referring to the Junit debugger in eclipse that will print out the method calls as they're put onto the stack. If you really want to see all the stuff that gets called in your program for a particular method and you have no idea what I'm talking about, but a while(true){} at the end and let the stack overflow. Scroll up and you should be able to see the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've finished my mentor's task. Turn out to being a profiling programming practice. I used ASM to help me print out all I need through reading binary class files.